# What is the minimum craft DC for a wand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

I'm GMing a group of mostly new players and one of the players has expressed intent in taking the craft wand feat. They had been asking questions about what they would need to do and the craft DC. I'm not overly familiar with the crafting rules other than 1000gp of crafting cost per day and the DC being 5+the caster level of the item.

What confuses me is what the caster level for the DC is. The minimum caster level for the craft wand feat is 5 so should the craft DC be 10 for a level 1 wand of magic missile or would it be a 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 5 + the wand’s caster level

Successfully [creating a magic item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/) requires a Spellcraft check with a DC equal to **5 + the item’s caster level**.

This is true to every magic item in the game (unless said otherwise). Which means that crafting a wand for a 1st level spell would be 6 (5 + 1 CL), the DC to craft a 1st level spell conjured by a 5th level caster (example, a Burning Hands of  5d4 damage) would be 10 (5 + 5 CL).

The level required to learn the feat is irrelevant here, because you can [create magic items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/) on whatever *caster level* you want, as long you respect these two rules:

- The item's caster level cannot be under the minimum caster level to cast the desired spell.
- The item's caster level cannot be higher than your own caster level.

> For potions, scrolls, and wands, the creator can set the caster level of an item at any number high enough to cast the stored spell but not higher than her own caster level. For other magic items, the caster level is determined by the item itself.